# Geodesic deviation equation in a non-coordinate basis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I've been trying to derive the geodesic deviation equation in an anholonomic basis and something is quite off. I'm pretty sure the equation should be the same no matter what set of vector fields we choose as basis: it's a tensor equation and as they are purely geometric objects, tensors are independent of the basis (only the components change, but not the tensor per se), so the equation should have the same form in any basis (e.g. in a generic non-coordinate basis, in a coordinate basis, in local normal coordinates, etc...). Everything works fine in a coordinate basis, but if I do the calculation in a anholonomic basis I get an extra term that cleraly should not be there. So please tell me what wrong assumption did I make.
Here's my procedure.

The Riemann curvature tensor has been defined in abstract notation through the curvature operator:
$$\mathbf{R}(\dots,\mathbf{C},\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})=\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})\mathbf{C}=([\nabla_{\mathbf{A}},\nabla_{\mathbf{B}}]-\nabla_{[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]})\mathbf{C}$$
By plugging in tangent vector $\mathbf{u}$ and basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_{\mu}$ and $\mathbf{e}_{\nu}$ one gets:
$$\mathbf{R}(\dots,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{e}_{\mu},\mathbf{e}_{\nu})=\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu \mathbf{u}-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu \mathbf{u}-\nabla_{[\mathbf{e}_\mu,\mathbf{e}_{\nu}]}  \mathbf{u}$$
But considering that by definition of the commutation coefficients
$$[\mathbf{e}_\mu,\mathbf{e}_{\nu}]=c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}\mathbf{e}_{\kappa}$$
and using the linearity of covariant differentiation, in component notation the equation should become like this:
$$R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\beta \mu \nu}u^{\beta}=u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu \mu}-u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu \nu}-c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\kappa}$$
Which can be equivalently written as
$$u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu \mu}=u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu \nu}+c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\kappa}+R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\beta \mu \nu}u^{\beta}$$
I'm gonna use this relationship, which I see no reason why would be incorrect (in a coordinate basis the commutation coefficients vanish so the equation is perfectly true even in a holonomic basis), by substituting it in the relative acceleration equation.
If $\mathbf{n}=n^{\alpha}\mathbf{e}_{\alpha}$ is the separation vector between two neighboring geodesics, and $\mathbf{u}$ is the vector tangent to the geodesic, then the relative acceleration $\mathbf{A}$  is:
$$\mathbf{A}=\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}} \mathbf{n}$$
But considering how $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are defined ($\mathbf{u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}$ with $\lambda$ an affine parameter of a certain geodesic, and $\mathbf{n}=\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ with n selector parameter that specifies which geodesic are we in), and using the symmetry of the Levi-Civita connection, we have:
$$[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{n}]=\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n}-\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{u}=\Big[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda},\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\Big]=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda \partial n}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial n \partial \lambda} = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{n}=\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{u}$$
Therefore
$$\mathbf{A}=\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{u}} \mathbf{n}=\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\nabla_{\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{u}$$
In components
$$A^{\alpha}=u^{\mu}(n^{\nu}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu})_{;\mu}=u^{\mu}n^{\nu}_{\,\,;\mu}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu}+u^{\mu}n^{\nu}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu\mu}\\ A^{\alpha}=u^{\mu}n^{\nu}_{\,\,;\mu}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu}+u^{\mu}n^{\nu}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu \nu}+u^{\mu}n^{\nu}c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\kappa}+R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\beta \mu \nu}u^{\beta}u^{\mu}n^{\nu}$$
But as the curve parametrized by a constant $n$ and varying $\lambda$ is a geodesic, the vector $\mathbf{u}$ parallel transports on its curve. Therefore, considering that the covariant derivative of a null tensor is also zero
$$u^{\alpha}_{\,\,; \mu }u^{\mu}=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad n^{\nu}(u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu}u^{\mu})_{;\nu}=0 \\ u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu\nu}u^{\mu}n^{\nu}+u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu}u^{\mu}_{\,\,;\nu}n^{\nu}=0$$
But since, from the equation proven before, $u^{\mu}_{\,\,;\nu}n^{\nu}=n^{\mu}_{\,\,;\nu}u^{\nu}$, I can rewrite this last one as:
$$u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu\nu}u^{\mu}n^{\nu}+u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu}n^{\mu}_{\,\,;\nu}u^{\nu}=0$$
Rearranging the dummy indices
$$u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\mu\nu}u^{\mu}n^{\nu}+u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\nu}n^{\nu}_{\,\,;\mu}u^{\mu}=0$$
Which can be substituted back in the equation for the relative acceleration:
$$A^{\alpha}=u^{\mu}n^{\nu}c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\kappa}+R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\beta \mu \nu}u^{\beta}u^{\mu}n^{\nu}$$
Now, in a coordinate frame all of that works perfctly as $c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}=0$ so we get the usual geodesic deviation equation:
$$A^{\alpha}=R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\beta \mu \nu}u^{\beta}u^{\mu}n^{\nu}$$
But the problem is that as this equation is tensorial in nature, and it can be written in abstract notation as
$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{R}(\dots,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{n})$$
without any mention of a basis whatsoever, it should have the same exact component form in any basis, independently of wheter is holonomic or anholonomic. I just don't get why the term $u^{\mu}n^{\nu}c_{\mu \nu}^{\,\,\,\,\kappa}u^{\alpha}_{\,\,;\kappa}$ doesn't somehow cancel out. What did I do wrong? I really can't see the mistake in my reasoning, and I've tried doing all the calculations over and over again several times.